# How to install Slim Cropper in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, cropper

I need to install Slim Cropper in Laravel (https://pqina.nl/slim/). I downloaded it and I have two files: slim.jquery.min and slim.min.css. How can I install it? I think I need to use the webpack.min.js, but I dont know how to use it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well thats depends how you want do it. the quickest way could be simply, Add them to resources/layouts/app.blade.php in `<head>`. (assuming app.blade.php is your main layout file which you extending in all child views.) and use it like you would be using in normal html. Nothing Fancy. and for urls you can always use

```
<!-- Styles -->
<link href="{{ asset('css/slim.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- script -->
<script src="{{ asset('js/slim.jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
```

which should load them from public/css and public/js folders.

read more about asset function here
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-asset